# What is in vs What is there in

Tags: difference, interrogatives, existentials

I can't quite figure if there is a difference between:

1. What is in the bag?
2. What is there in the bag?

And this:

1. Who is in the house?
2. Who is there in the house?

Comment: The way you answer it is different. 1 - A cat is in the bag / 2 - There's a cat in the bag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my opinion, the word *there* in both sentences is unnecessary. Or you replace bag or house with 'there'.

"What is in the bag?" good sentence

"What is <s>there</s> in the bag?" Or, "What is in there?"

"Who is in the house?" good sentence

"Who is <s>there</s> in the house?" Or, "Who is there?"

Comment: I sort of agree, but in spoken English, "there in" can work for emphasis. Consider, "Who is **there** in the house?". If the speaker points to a single house among several, and stresses "there", it acts as a guide for listeners to help them answer his question. Without such context, the word "there" adds nothing, and may even detract from clarity.

Comment: @RichF You  have a point, but I can't say I've heard that very often. It could be a regional thing. That sounds awkward to my ear -- but I might say, "Who is there in **that** house?"

Comment: Please point me to a rule in a book where I can read about it.

Comment: I cannot suggest a book, but perhaps this [LINK](https://www.englishgrammar.org/mistakes-prepositions-4/) might be of use.